# Can I stop the Firefox webRTC Sharing Indicator showing up?

Tags: firefox, i3

Using SwayWM (an i3 clone for Wayland), I get a frustrating tab that appears every time Firefox wants to access my webcam or microphone. Can I disable it?

[image: firefox-sharing-indicator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can kill it so quickly the user experience is the same! Add the following to your `~/.config/sway/config`:

```
for_window [app_id="firefox" title="Firefox — Sharing Indicator"] {
  kill
}
```

Comment: Thanks! On my system the title is `Firefox — Sharing Indicator` (the dash is different).

Comment: Yep I think it changed, going to update my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator` to `false` in `about:config`. I run Hyprland and couldn't fix it in any other way.